# Change image if selected button tab bar ios8

Tags: xcode, image, ios8, uitabbar, tap

i have inserted in my app a Tab Bar controller through the storyboard.
Now i need to change images of tap when they are selected.
How can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Go into the storyboard and select the view controller containing the tab you want to change (not the `UITabBarController`). In the inspector sidebar, you can choose the selected image and the default image. The images have to be 25x25 at 1x.